# get number of user connected lastweek (symfony - sql)

Tags: sql, symfony

I want to know the number of users logged in the last week from current day, that's why I try with this:

```
class UserRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findNumberLastWeek(){

    $dql = "SELECT count(p) FROM UserBundle:User p WHERE p.lastLogin >= 'DATEADD(day,-7, GETDATE())'";
    return $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery($dql)
        ->getSingleScalarResult();

}
```

but does not work :(

Comment: What you mean by " does not work" ? did you get an error msg? and are `p` a column in your table ?

Comment: no the result is 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this to do a similar feature in my app (counting user which were connected last day) :

```
   /**
     * Get the number of users which were connected between two dates
     * @param startDate $
     * @param endDate $
     * @return array
     */
    public function countUsersConnectedBetweenDate($startDate, $endDate) {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u');
        $qb
            ->select('COUNT(u) as numberConnectedUsersLastDay')
            ->where('u.lastLogin BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate')
            ->setParameter("startDate", $startDate)
            ->setParameter("endDate", $endDate);

        return $qb->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
    }
```

and in the controller (it's only to get last day connection) :

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $startYesterday = new \DateTime();
        $startYesterday->modify('yesterday');
        $endYesterday = new \DateTime();
        $endYesterday->modify('1 second ago');

        $countConnectedUsersLastDay = $em->getRepository(User::class)->countUsersConnectedLastDay($startYesterday, $endYesterday);
```

You can adjust the two dates to match what you want, I've not tested it but you can try something like that :

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $lastWeek = new \DateTime();
        $lastWeek->modify('-1 week');
        $now = new \DateTime();

        $countConnectedUsersLastDay = $em->getRepository(User::class)->countUsersConnectedLastDay($lastWeek, $now);
```

I hope that will help you.

Answer (score 0):

1. lastLogin should be a DATE type
2. Try the following: p.lastLogin <= DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), -7, 'day')

Comment: I think that Doctrine doesn't handle negative numbers in DATE_ADD. Try: WHERE p.lastLogin >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), 7, 'day')